# MyBatis: putting mapper xml files next to mapper interfaces under java

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I'm looking for a way to move the mapper xml files from under "resources" to under the "java" folder. I hope that's possible, because that way the interface.java file and mapper.xml file would be side by side.

I'm using Spring Boot.

application.properties:

```
mybatis.config-locations = classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

resources/mybatis-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
  <mappers>
    <mapper url="file:///home/abc/Projects/myproject/myapp/src/main/java/com/abc/services/myservice/MyMapper.xml"/>
  </mappers>
</configuration>
```

folder /home/abc/Projects/myproject/myapp/src/main/java/com/abc/services/myservice/

```
MyMapper.xml
MyMapper.java
```

When I run the app I get a 'not found' error :

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.abc.bm.services.myservice.MyMapper.findAll
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy resources files from source folder to the target output folder.

For maven this is done using `maven-resource-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources01</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you are using gradle the configuration is something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.xml"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Roman_Konoval, it worked, Thanks !! Only thing I had to change was <resource><directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory> (like in your gradle conf). Also I added it to the run conf in IntelliJ in 'before launch' section

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I use the `resource` attribute, as in:

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="mappers/account.xml" />
</mappers>
```

Just an idea that works well for me, using **relative** paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Resources like

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```